# Removing jQuery migrate and working with dependencies

Tags: php, customization, jquery

I have jQuery setup in my enqueue scripts section as a dependency, such as:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Now, I want to remove jquery-migrate, but keep jQuery itself obviously, so I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25977181/472501) stating to do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'remove_jquery_migrate' );

function remove_jquery_migrate( &$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()){
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery');
        $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), '1.2.1' );
    }
}
```

Firstly, I thought we had removed jQuery migrate here, so not sure what the need of adding the latest version of it is with the comment:

> 1.2.1 = latest version of jquery-migrate

Secondly, with the way I set my enqueue scripts up, how does that affect the dependencies since I have now removed `jQuery` and added `jquery-core`?

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First part...

OK, so in your theme/plugin you have:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

The first line, enqueuing `jquery` isn't necessary - you put `jquery` as dependency in second line, so it will be included anyway.

These lines inform WP that you want to enqueue given file as `scripts` and it needs script registered with handle `jquery` - so it will be enqueued automatically before your script.

### And the second part...

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'remove_jquery_migrate' );

function remove_jquery_migrate( &$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()){
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery');
        $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), '1.2.1' );
    }
}
```

As you can see in [Plugin API/Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), this hook is called pretty early... Waaaaay before `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

**And what it really does?**

It removes script with handle `jquery` from default scripts, and then adds it with different dependencies (only `jquery-core`).

`add` method comes from [`WP_Dependencies`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_dependencies/add/) class:

```
WP_Dependencies::add( string $handle, string $src, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, mixed $args = null )
```

### And why that version?

The version `1.2.1` is just a cache booster. WordPress does not analyze it. It is used as `?ver` param, so browsers have to reload that file, when the version changes... You can put anything in there - of course using real version of given script is a good idea ;)

Comment: That's excellent - thanks very much. Any idea how to get it placed in the footer? I couldn't quite understand what to pass to it with regards to the `args` parameter.